# determining the associated matrix has an endomorphism of R ^ n.

Tags: matrices

What is the method for determining the associated matrix has an endomorphism of R ^ n.

for example:

f is defined on  i³ with : ∀(x,y,z)  ∈ i³ , f(x,y,z) = (x+2z, 2y, 2x+z)
The canonical basis of  i³ : B(e1 (1,0,0); e2 (0,1,0); e1 (0,0,1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compute $f$ on the basis vectors, you find:

$f(\vec e_1)=1\vec e_1+0\vec e_2+2\vec e_3$

$f(\vec e_2)=0\vec e_1+2\vec e_2+0\vec e_3$

$f(\vec e_3)=2\vec e_1+0\vec e_2+1\vec e_3$

Take the coefficients matrix and do the transposition. The matrix you are looking for is
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1&0&2\\
0&2&0\\
2&0&1
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: in the second line of the matrix do you mean 0,3,0 right ?

Comment: @AimadMajdou sorry, there was an error, now i've edited, matrix is correct, the error was in the second equation ($3$ in place of $2$)